# Hyundai i10 EPS error

Tags: hyundai, power-steering, tachometer, i10, eps

I was driving my 2008 Hyundai i10 (1.1-litre IRDE) when suddenly the steering became very hard and the EPS warning light turned on. Later I realized that the tachometer had also conked out.

I searched the internet for similar cases and discovered that it is a pretty common issue in all older generation i10 and i20 cars.
I took my car to Koshala Hyundai, the authorized service center and asked them to plug in their scan tool. The scan didn't pick any error code whatsoever.

I was by the mechanic's side the whole time and I could feel that they don't have much experience with diagnosing errors using the scan tools.
He spoke with the in-charge when he couldn't find any definitive error and went on to explain to me what could've gone wrong. Apparently the power steering has 3 parts-

1. The column itself with the motor and everything
2. The EPS module while is placed just below the column.
3. The ECM module which is like the black box.

The EPS module costs almost Rs. 6000 (INR) and the ECM module costs over Rs. 40000 (INR). I am very apprehensive about their diagnosis especially when they cannot prove anything or even get an error code and I don't want to believe anything they say.  A lot of these ASSs have shady business practices and I don't want to spend more than 30% of my depreciated car's value over a mechanic's hunch.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem with their car? How did you resolve it?